# Problems mounting HPUX LVM+VXFS filesystem on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, hp-ux

I have a physical disk from a HPUX system that I need to access from a Debian Linux for ia64 system. From the [hpux-lvm-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpux-lvm-tools/) project I have the tools to access the HPUX LVMs (Linux LVM has a different format) and I also have the freevxfs driver.

I know beforehand that the disk has three partitions, and that the biggest one contains LVM volumes, and some of those are VxFS filesystems.

I can see the partitions:

```
# cat /proc/partitions

major minor  #blocks  name

   8       32  143374744 sdc
   8       33     512000 sdc1
   8       34  142452736 sdc2
   8       35     409600 sdc3
```

It finds a VG in one of the disk partitions:

```
# ./vgscan_hpux
On /dev/sdc2 - vg1328874723

# ./pvdisplay_hpux /dev/sdc2

PV General Information
----------------------
VG Creation Time        Fri Feb 10 12:52:03 2012
Physical Volume ID      1766760336 1328874723
Volume Group ID         1766760336 1328874723
Physical Volumes in VG  1766760336 1328874723
VG Actication Mode      0 - LOCAL
PE Size                 64 MBs

Lvol sizes
----------
lvol1 - 8 Extents - 512 MBs
lvol2 - 192 Extents - 12288 MBs
lvol3 - 16 Extents - 1024 MBs
  ...
lvol21 - 13 Extents - 832 MBs
lvol22 - 224 Extents - 14336 MBs
lvol23 - 16 Extents - 1024 MBs
```

Then I activate that VG and some new devices appear in my system:

```
# ./pvactivate_hpux /dev/sdc2
VG vg1328874723 Activated succesfully with 23 lvols.
#
# ll /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 59 Nov 26 16:08 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 26 16:38 vg1328874723-lvol1 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 26 16:38 vg1328874723-lvol10 -> ../dm-9
  ...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 26 16:38 vg1328874723-lvol8 -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Nov 26 16:38 vg1328874723-lvol9 -> ../dm-8
```

But:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/vg1328874723-lvol18 /mnt/tmp
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
# mount -t vxfs /dev/mapper/vg1328874723-lvol18 /mnt/tmp
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1328874723-lvol18,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

# lsmod |grep vxfs
freevxfs               23905  0
```

I also tried to identify the raw data with the file command and it just says 'data':

```
# file -s /dev/mapper/vg1328874723-lvol18
/dev/mapper/vg1328874723-lvol18: symbolic link to `../dm-17'
# file -s /dev/dm-17
/dev/dm-17: data
#
```

Any clues?

Comment: It would be nice if you added vgdisplay for the vg1328874723.  Also, take a look at /proc/filesystems.  There is no vxfs in Linux, but it might be called 'freevxfs' instead.

Comment: I don't have a vgdisplay_hpux utility, only pvactivate_hpux  pvdisplay_hpux and vgscan_hpux. The standard vgdisplay doesn't recognize my VG. /proc/filesystems shows vxfs (without 'nodev')

Comment: Try running fdisk -l against the devmapper and see what kind of filesystem it reports.

Comment: It says "Disk /dev/dm-17 doesn't contain a valid partition table". I tried several LVs

Answer (score 2):

In the project page doesn't tell anything about which layout of VxFS are supported.

So I suggest you first check on your HPUX the VxFS layout

```
fstyp -v /dev/vg00/lvol3 | grep -i version
```

Then check if your VxFS layout version is supported by hpux-lvm-tools.

PS1: Partition 1: EFI, Partition 2 PV of OS, Partition 3 may contain support utilities.
PS2: I can't see the link to post this as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I think you need more reputation to add comments

Comment: That command says "version 5", however I can't find which versions are supported in the FreeVxFS documentation

Comment: Ask to the developers of FreeVxFS. BTW if you are working in a production environment, I do not recommend do you use FreeVxFS. It could be dangerous. Is it absolutely necessary you present HPUX disk to Linux server?

Comment: No, we just want to extract some files from a server that is not working anymore

Comment: If you could check the veritas version in your HPUX server, why you can't send the files over the netwok? FTP, SCP, NFS.... :)

Comment: That's another machine identical to the dead one

Comment: If the disks are from SAN, present to the other HPUX server. Could you?

Comment: I'm remembering.... linux does not activate lvs automatically when vg becomes activated. You you could try to execute lvchange -a y lvnameX
Also you could post the output of "vgdisplay -v vg1328874723" to see detailed information.

Comment: Those are the normal Linux LVM commands, but for HPUX-type LVM there is only pvactivate_hpux, pvdisplay_hpux and vgscan_hpux. I checked the source code of freevxfs and I think it doesn't support VXFS 5...